# Remote connection to Pi succeeds or fails apparently at random

Tags: pi-2, remote, noobs, vnc

I'm attempting to remotely access the desktop of my Raspberry Pi 2 using VNC. I followed [these instructions](https://www.raspberrypi.org/documentation/remote-access/vnc/README.md) to install TightVNC Server on the Pi (which is running NOOBS) and [these instructions](https://www.raspberrypi.org/documentation/remote-access/vnc/windows.md) to install TightVNC Viewer on a PC running Windows 7.

I'm specifying `192.168.#.#:1` or `192.168.#.#::5901` as the remote host in the "New TightVNC Connection" dialog, where `192.168.#.#` is the IP address of the Pi determined using `hostname -I`. With either of these, the connection sometimes succeeds but sometimes fails with the error:

"Error in TightVNC Viewer: A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond."

I've also tried connecting to the Pi using `telnet 192.168.#.# 5901`; similarly, this sometimes works and sometimes doesn't (when it doesn't work, the error is, "Could not open connection to the host, on port 5901: Connect failed").

Generally, I'll be able to connect successfully for a while, then connection attempts will fail, followed by a period where they succeed again, etc. (All using the same vncserver session on the Pi.)

Any suggestions about what might be causing this behaviour would be appreciated!

**EDIT:** during a period when connection attempts fail, it seems that loading something over the network on the Pi's end (e.g., visiting a new web page in the Epiphany web browser) will result in connection attempts succeeding again (but only for a while).

For example, if I start pinging the Pi (via `ping 192.168.#.#` in the Windows command prompt) during a period when connection attempts fail, the result is "Request timed out". If I visit a website on the Pi while Windows is still pinging it (e.g., between the second and third pings), the result of the next ping attempt will be "Reply from 192.168.#.#: bytes=32 [...]" and a subsequent VNC connection attempt will succeed.

Comment: When you can't connect from your PC, can you ping the PI from the PC?

Comment: @Kolban if I ping the Pi during a period when connection attempts fail, the ping request times out. If I ping the Pi during a period when connection attempts succeed, the ping elicits a reply.

Comment: As an educated guess, I would suggest that the WiFi device is suspending itself due to lack of activity.  Have a google search on this notion as it relates to the Raspberry Pi.  There are settings available where the WiFi device can be prevented from going to sleep.